# richfaces selecting a query after page loaded without waiting

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, jsf, richfaces

I am using richfaces , hibernate  and ejb. I hava a page and I am selecting a query that is take 1 minute while opening page. However, this makes user uncomfortable because page is coming too late.

Because of this problem, how can I using ajax to solve this problem. I want to show "loading" icon and open page. and after opening the page , I want to get the query from database and show result list istead of "loading " image. Thanks to this users don't have to wait for opening page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the JQuery [.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method, you can click an invisible button. This invisible button should be like this ...

```
<a4j:commandButton status="pageLoadStatus" style = "display:none;" 
    actionListener="#{someBean.loadData}"
    ajaxSingle="true" id = "hiddenButton"
    reRender="panelToRerender" >
</a4j:commandButton>
```

In the loadData method in the managed bean, write your code to fetch DB records.